# Get size of sent curl request

Tags: curl

Is there a way to get the size of a `curl` request programmatically?

E.g. if I do

```
curl 'http://www.example.com/url' \
-H 'Cookie: cookie=cookiedata;' \
-H 'X-CSRFToken: csrffake' \
--data 'example=moredata \
--compressed
```

I want to know how big my sent request is?

Comment: The header request size?

Comment: @Braiam The size of the resulting request (excluding ethernet/ip layers). So header + data I think.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok after some `man curl` digging, I think I've found out the answer, though I'm not 100% sure about it's validity:

> ```
>  -w, --write-out <format>
>      Defines  what  to display on stdout after a completed and successful operation.
>      [...]
>      The variables present in the output format will be substituted by the
>      value or text  that  curl thinks fit, as described below.
>      All variables are specified as %{variable_name} and to output a
>      normal % you just write them as %%.
>
>      [...]
>           size_request   The total amount of bytes
>                          that were sent in the HTTP request.
>
>           size_upload    The total amount of bytes that were uploaded.
> ```

That means adding a `-w '%{size_request} %{size_upload}'` and then adding the resulting numbers in the output after the request will give you the request size in total.

Comment: Note: This doesn't include TLS overhead should you be using HTTPs.